# How to code a button with differents effects when pressed multiple times

Tags: android, imageview, android-studio-3.0, togglebutton

I  may be asking a basic question, but to be honest, I have no real developement or code knowledge. I've been requested to make a prototybe of some basic app, that is supposed mainly to be buttons on screens, activable or desactivable. I've written some kind of TL;DR in case my explanations are bad

I've been coding this on Android Studio 3.0, I (hardly) managed to place PNGs files on the screen, making it looking like a button.
Thing is, while some parts of the app are mainly constituted with independants togglable button. There a part where pressing a button must deselect the others. AND, if this button is pressed a second time open another activities.

Here's part of my code I'm using.

This one for independants buttons

```
indbutton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        // track if the image is selected or not
        boolean isSelected = true;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(isSelected) {
                indbutton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.indbutton1slct);
            } else {
                indbutton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.indbutton1nosl);
            }
            // toggle the boolean
            isSelected = !isSelected;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And this one for going into other activities

```
  movements.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gestesActivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), movements.class);
            startActivity(movementsActivity);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

TL;DR
How should I proceed to have a mix of pressing button, disabling others enabled, then, when pressed a second time, I go to another activity.

Thank you for any help :) -Pliskin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do that. Let's say you have 4 buttons.

```
// your class fields
boolean [] alreadyTouched = new boolean[4];
```

For each of the 4 buttons :

```
button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!alreadyTouched[0]){
            setAlreadyTouched(0);
            // one click actions here
        }else{
            // second click's action
        }       


    }
});
```

Now you make a private method in your class :

```
private void setAlreadyTouched(int index){
    for (int i = 0; i< alreadyTouched.length; i++)
        alreadyTouched[i] = false;
    if(index != -1)
        alreadyTouched[index] = true;
}
```

And to reset your boolean array when the button looses the focus :

```
button0.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus){
        if(!hasFocus)
            setAlreadyTouched(-1);
    }
});
```

You can do exactly the same thing but with an array of int if you want more than two clicks with some slight modifications. For example :

```
// your class fields
int[] alreadyTouched = new int[4];
```

Your privat method :

```
private void setAlreadyTouched(int index){
    if(index == -1){
        for (int i = 0; i< alreadyTouched.length; i++)
            alreadyTouched[i]=0;
    }else
        alreadyTouched[index] = alreadyTouched[index] +1 ;
}
```

Then just add some if in your onClickListeners :

```
button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setAlreadyTouched(0);
        switch(alreadyTouched[0]){            
            case 1:
            // one click actions here
            break:
            case 2:
            // second click's action
            break:
            // ... and so on
            default:
            // action for max number of clicks here.
        }                   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I don't have much knowledge (I Macgyvered the whole app, I don't even know how I managed to make it working), I'am not sure if all this codes must go inside one single file.  
I did put all in the same file.java. Somehow I feel this isn't the right thing to do, but i'm clueless, and the only one who cares to develop the concept.

Any more precisions on where should I place thoses parts ? Sorry for wasting your time, i'm no developer at first :/

I merged it all. Let me upload a screenshot i'll edit here in a minute

Comment: Urgh, just at the moment i click edit i get canceled by some countdown
https://puu.sh/BVYsb/3f9fcc9d9b.png
don't consider the red unsolved symbols as... unsolved, they are but it's glitching again at the moment.

Comment: The array declaration should typically be placed just below "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {".
The Listeners should be placed inside the onCreate method.
The private method is inside your Activity class but outside of all other methods.
Yes, all of this belongs to the same activity.

Comment: Don't put the "onClick(View view)" inside the other onClick(View view).
I recommend you try to learn some android basics, practice is a great teacher but theory still is necessary.

Comment: Alright, I've managed to get it working ! I know I'm lacking a lot of basics knowledge. I didn't thought that placing a background a just few buttons would be so hard, and the more I did, the more I got requested in a very short period of time. Excepted 2 or 3 things more, the prototype is almost complete :D

As I managed to merge correctly your code, there is only one slight issue that I maybe responsible.

Comment: When I click on let's say Button0, it get selected. then I click it again, it get to the activity. Nice ! Let's reset now, If I click Button0, it get selected. Now if I click Button1, it get to Button 1 activity immediately, without disabling Button0, skipping the step on enabling it once. Any hints ? Then I should be done with this issue. Many thanks for the time you took for me.

Comment: When implementing button1, button 2 etc... you must change the index when calling the private method. Example for button 2 : `if(!alreadyTouched[2]){
            setAlreadyTouched(2);...}`
And don't forget that indexes in arrays start from 0 in java, therefore button2 in my example would actually be my third button.

Comment: Also, every button should have its own Listeners (both). button1.setOnClickListener ; button1.setOnFocusChangeListener... etc
You can put them one after the other in the onCreate method.
There are other ways of doing it, but they're a bit more complicated and not required if you have only a few buttons, that's ok then.

Comment: It's working, I had to find and complete some part of your code but I managed to complete the thing ! 
I did explained what I've done here
https://puu.sh/BWqov/6f66a9170f.txt

Thank you very much, this is a great improvement.
I'll make sure to recontact you if this thing work ! 
-Pliskin